# What is the piano piece played at the end of airplane flashback on episode 19 of Nodame Cantabile season 1?

Tags: music, nodame-cantabile

There's a piano piece playing at the end of the airplane flashback in season 1 episode 19 of *Nodame Cantabile* at around 8:21.

What is that piano piece called?

Answer (score 1):

It's the piano/slow version of the opening theme, "Allegro Cantabile". ([YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fRu8EcZko4))